# Rescale a drawing made of SVGs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, svg, scaling

I have a drawing made of SVGs that I would like to rescale to be smaller. Importantly, because all the drawings is made of separate strokes, the svg strokes need to be rescaled proportionally.

Toy dataset (drawing of a cat):

```
d = {'strokeNum': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
     'svg': [
"M108,198c0,-11.77932 31.49422,-78.49422 40,-87c0.25776,-0.25776 3.60098,-0.13301 4,0c6.70269,2.23423 45,56.0804 45,60", 
"M263,177c0,-12.14853 8.95882,-23.35751 14,-34c7.90612,-16.6907 17.66683,-40.66683 30,-53c1.83615,-1.83615 15.37069,22.01292 17,25c1.28688,2.35927 2.64589,4.67866 4,7c12.78993,21.9256 25.26076,43.40977 39,65", 
"M203,231c-7.57098,0 5.70961,9.29039 11,4c4.07789,-4.07789 -20.03725,-2 -11,-2", 
"M283,230c-2.33333,0 -4.66667,0 -7,0c-21.05637,0 -1.55503,9.27752 9,4c0.80312,-0.40156 3.60646,-2.39354 3,-3c-1.89551,-1.89551 -14.83206,0 -18,0",
"M281,277c18.46588,0 36.46579,-2 55,-2", 
"M297,290c18.20057,0 47.79393,-2.20607 62,12",
"M292,298c3.49249,0 33.2709,24.2709 39,30",
"M213,270c-20.07389,0 -54.90686,5.90686 -70,21", 
"M212,290c-7.0005,0 -16.23,-1.56231 -23,0c-14.95762,3.45176 -30.65923,20 -46,20", 
"M212,306c-14.08518,0 -25.76961,21 -40,21", 
"M229,319c0,16.3023 32.26476,-1 34,-1", 
"M108,264c0,25.00606 -7.4667,89.22217 5,110c39.35056,65.58427 187.90959,72.45411 241,26c29.32855,-25.66248 33.41273,-66.59138 44,-101c0.46113,-1.49868 5.12178,-36 0,-36"
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Desired output:

a new column with rescaled svgs (smaller in this case)

The svgs should be proportional so that the new cat drawing just looks like a smaller version of the original drawing.

Comment: Why are you trying to resize an svg file directly? Are you unable to control how the file is used and displayed? If you are the one rendering it then it should be fairly easy to scale it when drawing the image.

Comment: @Locke I'm displaying each svg on a canvas in which users will make responses to what they think each stroke looks like. So that's why the file is generated and organized as separate svgs, rather than as a single e.g., png file.

Comment: psychcoder: The major point of SVG is that's is scalable—that's what the "S" in its name stands for—so it should be unnecessary to do what you want (assuming you're able to properly render one). Stating that you're "displaying each svg on a canvas" is too vague to determine what's actually occurring.